# Using stl::set in implementation of Map data structure

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set

For a Lab in school, we have to implement the Map data structure ourselves, using sets.

My professor wants us to use our own implementation of Set by including our own file:

```
#include "../Lab8/Set.h"
```

However my Set.h isn't complete. What I wanted to ask was how to include the stl set for use in my program.
Here it is:

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

//Map.h
#include "Pair.h"
#include <set>
//#include "../Lab8/Set.h"

using namespace std;

template <class key, class value>
class Map : public Set < Pair < key, value > >
{
public:
    typedef Set < Pair < key, value > > parent;
    typedef Set_iterator < Pair < key, value> > iterator;

    Map() : parent() {}

    iterator find(const key & k);
    value & operator[](const key & k);
    void erase(const key & k);
};
#endif
```

I know that it has there has to be something done with the template, but I can't figure it out. 
I've looked up things about allocators, but much of it didn't make sense. I apologize if this question is worded incorrectly.

Comment: Since nobody else knows what your homegrown `Set` is all about, it's not possible for anyone else to suggest how you could use it to implement map semantics. You have to examine, and study what the `Set` is all about, and figure it out yourself.

Comment: A `Map<K,V>` is definitely not a `Set<Pair<K,V>>`. The set could have `<1,1>` and `<1,2>` in it as those are different pairs, but the map can only have one value for `1`. The connection is more in the reverse: a `Set<K>` is sort of like a `Map<K, Nothing>`.